# Which deductions can be made from the sets equality $B \setminus A = A \setminus B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The choices are either

1. $A \cup B = B$
2. $B \setminus A = B$
3. $A = B$
4. $A \cap B = B$

I'm stomped. My best guess was $A=B$ but I'm confused on how to solve it correctly.

Comment: This is not a well designed problem, since 3 implies both 1 and 4. At any rate, draw diagrams! For each of the four cases, draw a diagram representing that case, and check whether $B\setminus A = A\setminus B$.

Comment: One of these things imply two others.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Using `\setminus` gives you the correct spacing without needing to manually space the text.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Thanks, I had forgotten the existence of this operator !

Comment: I wrote the problem exactly how it is written on the practice exercise in my textbook. The answer isn't multiple choice either.  It states, "Determine the relationship between A and B, if we know the following"

Comment: "Determine the relationship between A and B, if we know the following": you have to write this sentence in your question ! It completely modifies it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $B \setminus A =B\cap A^c$ and  $A \setminus B=A\cap B^c$ are disjoint sets.

Comment: I'm only in my first week of Discrete math. Your answer confuses me.

Comment: @JeremyJackson I mean that  $(B \setminus A)\cap(A \setminus B)=\emptyset$. Since they are equal it follows that they are both empty: $B \setminus A=A \setminus B=\emptyset$. What may we conclude?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. Since both A and B = 0 (sorry I don't know how to do the symbols yet), that means A = B?

Comment: Yes, now $B \setminus A=\emptyset$ means that $B\subseteq A$ and $A \setminus B=\emptyset$ means that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I understand how I got the original answer now. Is there a way we can prevent edits to our questions? I know it may have been a proper correction, but the rewording of the question, confused me even more than I was originally. I'm a beginner and I'm sure I'll learn over the next 2 months.

Comment: Question can be edited by users with enough reputation. I am sure that you will learn quickly how to write a question properly. See the "help" button above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in A$ and suppose that $x \notin B$. Then $x  \in A \setminus B=B \setminus A$, hence $x \in B$. Contradiction !

This gives $A \subseteq B$.

In a similar way we derive $B \subseteq A$. Hence $A=B$ and $A \setminus B=B \setminus A= \emptyset$.

Comment: A little Latex remark: \varnothing is a little prettier than \emptyset

Comment: @JeanMarie I disagree.

Comment: @Stefan Mesken It's your right ! It's rare that two persons are in full agreement on aesthetical points of view...

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, that's my point. I don't think that a comment on stylistic choices that don't offer any utilitarian benefits is helpful or on-topic on this platform. [Note that \emptyset offers a small utilitarian benefit since it helps the search engine to find relevant posts if someone looks for topics involving the empty set. That's very minor, though.]

Comment: @Stefan Mesken It's also your right to say that... Look at the remark Asaf Karagila (who is a veteran on this site) just made to me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the assumption $x\in B\setminus A$ leads to a contradiction if $B\setminus A=A\setminus B$.

This because $x\in B\setminus A$ implies $x\in B$ and $x\in A\setminus B$ implies $x\notin B$.

So apparantly it is a wrong assumption and we conclude that $B\setminus A=\varnothing$ or equivalently $B\subseteq A$.

Likewise we find that $A\subseteq B$.

This together proves that $A=B$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.